# Scrape and compare and Web page data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a web page with data in different tables. I want to extract a particular table and compare with an excel sheet and see whether there are any differences. Note the web page is in a internal domain. I tried with requests and beautifulsoup but I got 401 error. Could anyone help how I can achieve this?

Comment: Could you please post the code that gives you 401?

Comment: I have used the below code, but I get 401 error. 


import requests
from bs4 from BeautifulSoup

values = {}
values['username']= ""
values['password] = ""
url = "" #Internal domain URL
r = requests.get(url,data=values)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(t.text,'html.parser')
soup.findAll('table')

Answer (score 0):

401 is an Unauthorized Error - which suggests your username and password may be getting rejected, or their format not accepted. Review your credentials and the exact format / data names expected by the page to ensure you're correctly trying to connect.